# Bootstrap.ModalPane redirects to index?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I added a bootstrap modalPane to my app with the url:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/#/pieces
```

The pane shows up, but when it closes it redirects my url to:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/#/
```

Can someone explain this?  Or direct me to some other resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons in the twitter bootstrap modal demos have href # tags in them. You'll need to change the  buttons to ember buttons and then hide the modal from the action handler. Something like:

```
  <a class="btn btn-small" {{action back}}>
    <i class="icon-remove"></i> Cancel
  </a>
```

You may also want to look at this project which wraps a lot of twitter bootstrap with ember.

https://github.com/emberjs-addons/ember-bootstrap